# radaeepdf cordova plugin integration with Ionic2

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2

I am trying to integrate radaeepdf cordova plugin. I tried there default cordova setup.

Pdf is opening from www/ folder. But it is not opening from sdcard/download. It is showing invalid path.

Has anyone successfully integrate this plugin into android and read file from sd card.

Please help if possible.

EDIT-1::

```
`ngAfterViewInit(){

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this._file.externalRootDirectory);

        RadaeePDFPlugin.open(
          {
              url: "file:///storage/emulated/0/"+"Download/test.PDF",
              password: "", //password if needed
              readOnlyMode: false,
              gotoPage: 2
          },
          function(message) {
                alert("Success: " + message);
          },
          function(err){
              alert("Failure: " + err);
          }
      );

    },5000)`
```

Comment: Can you share the `code` of your implementation?

Comment: @Sampath, please see edit. the plugin is not accepting SD card path.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your path is wrong.Please try it as shown below.

```
url: "file:///mnt/sdcard/Download/Test.pdf", //in case of pdf is in the device file system
```

See that too on [**doc here**](https://github.com/gearit/RadaeePDF-Cordova#open-pdf-from-file-system).

Comment: Its not working, it still give error: open failed access denied or invalid path

Comment: may be you need to give `password: "" //password if needed` then?

Comment: There is no password in file.

Comment: Hmm..You can log this issue then on their git repo?